# How to reset internal database timestamp counter?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, t-sql, timestamp

I have an application where there is one master (central) database and then many distributed client databases. Some of the tables have timestamp columns. So, those columns get populated with the current database timestamp (select @@DBTS). But when I rebuild a distributed client database, I need to reset the new database's timestamp counter to something bigger than what was last used. Currently, i just spin in an update till the counter becomes larger than the last used value. But, my question is: Is there a way to reset the database's internal timestamp counter to another value? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION(). MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION is a non-deterministic function that returns the lowest active rowversion value in the current database

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839514.aspx) for details.

Comment: Well ... I don't want to retrieve the (minimum) active timestamp value used ... I need to change the database's internal timestamp counter to the value I want. Because when I create a new database, the internal timestamp value is going to be small ... then i load my data from a central db ... then i need to spin in an update till the internal timestamp counter becomes larger than a value I've already used ... Rather than spinning in an update to increment the timestamp counter, I just want to tell the database to update it's internal timestamp counter to x value.

Answer (score 0):

@michael-lee maybe you've solved your issue, after so many years. But I was searching something related to your request, and I've found an answer here [ROWVERSION is an Alias for TimeStamp Data Type]
http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_C124042

The answer is NO:
"The ROWVERSION counter cannot be reset."
and moreover
"A ROWVERSION field value cannot be user-specified; the value is always supplied from the ROWVERSION counter."

Maybe it's useful to someone else.